# Image upload as multi part to server folder is not working in android

Tags: php, android, image, upload

Uploading image to server folder from android gallery is not working. It does not any exception and the image is not uploaded to the folder. Googled all the sample examples and tried many solutions but nothing works for me.

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.volleyupload;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UploadImageDemo extends Activity {

TextView tv;
Button b;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("Uploading file path :- '/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160112_104150.jpg'");

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadImageDemo.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            tv.setText("uploading started.....");
                        }
                    });
                    int response= uploadFile("/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160112_104150.jpg");

                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    String upLoadServerUri = "http://appsinbox.com/appstimesheetnew/testup.php";
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
        return 0;
    }
    try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        final String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
        if(serverResponseCode == 200){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("File Upload Completed.");

                }
            });
        }

        //close the streams //
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        ex.printStackTrace();

        Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    dialog.dismiss();
    return serverResponseCode;
}
}
```

And php code is below

```
$target_path1 = "/var/www/vhosts/logineduhub.com/appsinbox/appstimesheetnew/uploads/";
/* Add the original filename to our target path. Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if( chmod($target_path1, 0777) ) {
// more code
chmod($target_path1, 0755);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1))
    {
        echo "hi";
    echo "The first file " . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']) . " has been uploaded.";
}
else {
    echo "bye";
    echo "There was an  error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " . $target_path1;
}


}
else
{
echo "Couldn't do it.";
}
```

Comment: Anything inside the logcat? You're doing networking on the main thread, which is not the right way to do it.

Comment: for the android part, u can use picasso library to upload image

Comment: Nothing on logcat @Egor

Comment: just a suggestion! try using volley it's more simpler and faster!

Comment: Did you add internet permission to your manifest?

Comment: Is there way to upload image as file using picasso?

Comment: try [this example](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/) this works for me

Comment: Tried that example.. but in server side they couldnt able to read the encoded string since it is very lengthy string. @ Samrat Das

Comment: Try this to [pick image from gallery](https://acomputerengineer.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/pick-image-from-gallery-before-and-after-kitkat-version-in-android/) and try this to [upload the image to server(PHP)](https://acomputerengineer.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/upload-image-from-android-app-to-php-server-without-any-library/) without any libraries on android side

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it (more or less :))

Android:

```
public String uploadFile(String u, String imageFilePath, String filename) {

    String attachmentName = "image";
    String attachmentFileName = filename + ".jpg";
    String crlf = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(imageFilePath);

        try {

            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;
            URL url = new URL(u);
            httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                

            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());

            request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
            request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + attachmentName + "\";filename=\"" + attachmentFileName + "\"" + crlf);
            request.writeBytes(crlf);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                request.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            request.writeBytes(crlf);
            request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);

            request.flush();
            request.close();

            int responseCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();

            String inputLine = "";

            if (responseCode == 200) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream()));
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
            }

        } catch (MalformedInputException e) {
            Log.v("Err", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            Log.v("Err", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.v("Err", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Err", e.getMessage());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v("Err", e.getMessage());
    }

    return response.toString();

}
```

and php

```
<?php

    define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);       

    $response = 0;

    if($_FILES){        
        if(!$_FILES['image']['error']){
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){                 

                $dirpath = 'path to save file';

                if(!is_dir($dirpath)){
                    mkdir($dirpath,0777);
                }

                $destination = $dirpath.DS.$_FILES['image']['name'];
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination)){
                    $response = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo $response;

 ?>
```